# Can you climb a ladder into space?

Tags: physics, space, astronaut

**Can one climb a ladder into Space?**

If you have a heavy sphere traveling in Earth's orbit and attach a super-strong, superlight cable to it, down to Earth, could you travel via some sort of carriage along that cable out of Earth's orbit? Or, is escape velocity some fundamental rule?

As we go further into space, gravity lessens (and time does what? Goes slower?). And thus the escape velocity must decrease as well.

If you get the combination of distance from Earth and weight of the sphere that serves as the plumbline plunger, just right, you could adjust the strain on the cable right?

Saw it in a Star Trek movie and can't stop thinking about whether it is doable and if is, then why hasn't it been started already?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [Space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator)?

Comment: According to the Ladder saga, yes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAlXll4VDgo&t=199s

Comment: The amount of oxygen you'd need to carry with you (not to mention food/water clothing and finally a vacuum suite), surely the answer is no way. The greater the exertion, the greater the O2 need. People have trouble carrying the O2 up the 5 miles of Everest that they use multiple camps which are stocked beforehand so they don't have to carry stuff that far.

Comment: mandatory XKCD: https://what-if.xkcd.com/126/

Comment: (a) This appears to not be a question about worldbuilding, which is the development of an imaginary world of your own creation. (b) The idea of space elevators has been around for a long time. (c) We don't do it because we don't have the technology to do it. Don't get trapped in the (increasingly common) belief that just because we can imagine it, it must be real and possible. If you think the cables are a problem, think about how to keep it anchored to the planet.

Answer (score 5):

Escape velocity applies only if an object is trying to leave a gravitational well by coasting.

If you had a suitable road (and a humongous amount of time...) you could simply walk or drive away from any gravity well, aside from a black hole.

Think of it like the difference between wanting to spring jump from sea level to the top of Mount Everest and instead climbing it: with the jump you need a minimum initial velocity to reach the top, with climbing you don't.

If instead of a road you have a ladder or a rope, you could leisurely climb it and go to space. The problem would then be staying in space: the orbital velocity in LEO is around 8 km/s, which is not achievable by running.

Randall Munroe described a similar process in his own style [here](https://what-if.xkcd.com/157/)

Comment: Voted up just for the pertinent by always entertaining Randall Munroe cartoon.

Comment: [This one found by Trish](https://what-if.xkcd.com/126/) seems to suit better to the question title. However your choice suits the question body better.

Answer (score 1):

The concept exists and it's called a [space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator), but it's a theoretical concept. If we could manufacture a cable from materials like carbon nanotubes, for example, ascending into orbit without needing to achieve escape velocity could be possible. Gravity weakens with altitude, reducing the strain on the cable as you go higher. I think the idea is that the other end of the space elevator would be at 36000 kilometers above Earth, which is the height at which geostatic satellites orbit. Gravity there is almost zero [indeed](https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/gravity-acceleration-by-altitude).

However, the actual implementation is way out of reach of current technology!

Comment: The *center* of the space elevator is at geostationary orbit. The elevator has to extend past that in order to keep the tether taught (despite older concepts, you don't need a captured asteroid counterweight, just extend your cable far enough to where centripetal force pulls it taut.) Also, we are about at the technological point to build a *lunar* space elevator, even if not an Earth one, and the ends of both elevators would be close enough to launch from one and catch the other (with planning and amazing targeting computers).

Comment: @lilHar cool! Thanks for the updated information. I hadn't thought about this since graduate school :)